# How to copy files using Ansible from local to remote with regex?

Tags: regex, ansible

I need to copy files from local server (ansible host) to remote machine. But need to filter it first with regex.
I tried to do it using **with_items**, but seems it execute command on remote machine only.
Also I tried to do it using **with_fileglob** but seems it doesn't understand regex.
How it's possible to do this?

I tried this way:

```
 - name: Prepare list of packages to copy
    find:
      paths: "/srv/test_files/"
      patterns: '(^((?!.*dbg).)*arm64.*$)'
      use_regex: yes
    register: file_list

  - name: Copying deb packaged to {{deb_path}} on a remote host
    copy:
      src: "{{item.path}}"
      dest: "/srv/tmp/"
    with_items:
      - "{{file_list.files}}"
```

In this case ansible tries to copy prepared list from remote, not from local machine.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please update the question and show some code around `regex`, `with_*` that didn't work. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are you trying to find the list of files on Ansible control machine or on target?

Comment: Need to find list on Ansible control machine (mounted NAS) and copy that list to remote. I do files filtering with regex, because didn't find another suitable way.

Comment: Then the `find` should be run on Ansible control machine using `delegate_to: localhost`.

Comment: OMG. Your'e awesome. Please post this as answer, I'll mark it as correct answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this case ansible tries to copy prepared list from remote, not from local machine.

The reason for this is because the `find` operation is also running the target node. Since the files are on the Ansible control machine, `find` should be run on the same.

A minor change in your `find` task like below should take care of this:

```
 - name: Prepare list of packages to copy
    find:
      paths: "/srv/test_files/"
      patterns: '(^((?!.*dbg).)*arm64.*$)'
      use_regex: yes
    register: file_list
    delegate_to: localhost       # search files on localhost instead of target
```